# what it would be the correct way to write this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, classification

I'm trying to classify the ages into four groups, what it would be the best way to do it?.
Sorry for the dumb question, I'm pretty noobie.
This is what I have so far.

```
ages = df['Age']
age_groups = {'zero_to_twenty' :[],
             'twenty_one_to_fourty': [],
             'fourty_one_to_sixty': [],
             'sixty_one_and_above': []}
for age in ages:
    if age <= 20:
        age.append(age_groups['zero_to_twenty'])
    if age >=21 <= 40:
        age.append(age_groups['twenty_one_to_fourty'])
    if age >=41 <= 60:
        age.append(age_groups['fourty_one_to_sixty'])
    if age >=61:
        age.append(age_groups['sixty_one_and_above'])
```

Comment: If everything's working and you're trying to get feedback, you should go to [codereview.SE].

Comment: But I also see that you're using the variable 'age' twice with different meanings. If there's a problem, you need debugging details. Please make this into a [mre].

Comment: If you use pandas (as possibly implied by your use of `df['age']`) you might want to avoid the usage of for-loops altogether as pandas subsetting operations are much more efficient. In pandas, your problem would be addressed by by using `.cut()`; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html. There you could use `bins` and achieve your result easier.

Comment: I think your `age.append(age_groups["<group_name>"])` lines should be `age_groups["<group_name>"].append(age)`

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `elif` to avoid unnecessary comparisons.

Second, `switch` performs better than many if else statements. Since Python does not have the [`match` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#the-match-statement) (which seems `switch` equivalent) yet, you can do something like:

```
group = [
    'zero_to_twenty',
    'twenty_one_to_fourty',
    'fourty_one_to_sixty',
    'sixty_one_and_above'
]
for age in ages:
    if age >= 61: 
        age = 61
    age_groups[group[age // 20]].append(age)
```

Comment: +1 for answer, but on a side note python has just announced match statements for 3.10 or 3.11 so we should a python equivalent of switch very soon!

Comment: @dangee1705 Wow, I did not know that. That's a very good news! :D